# Looping through arraylist of arraylists

Tags: java, arraylist, collections

I have this code below to count the frequency of a string in an ArrayList

```
public static int count (ArrayList<String> c, String str){

        int num = 0;

        num = Collections.frequency(c, str);        


        return num;


    }
```

What I have to do now is to improve this so that the function takes in `ArrayList<ArrayList<String>>` and can loop through the set of Arraylists and Count the occurrences of the String.  Any ideas would be great.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use two nested for loops, looping through each list with the first one and looping through each element of the current list with the second, i.e.:

```
int count = 0;
for (ArrayList<String> list : lists) {
    for (String string : list) { 
        if (list.equals("something")) count++;
    }
}
```

To compute the frequency you'll also need to count the total number of elements in all the lists, but I'll leave that to you as it should be straightforward now.

Comment: Your answer helped me but you don't need to nest. 

for(ArrayList<String> list : c){
   num = num + Collections.frequency(list, str);
  }

Comment: I have never used that type of for loop before thanks

Answer (score 0):

Dude, you described the algorithm, it won't get simpler than that. Just code the thing.

Keep in mind that `Collections::frequency` is misnamed (IMHO), it should be `count`.

Answer (score 0):

In java 8 use the **stream**

```
public void findOccurenceInLists(ArrayList<ArrayList<String>> lists, String myStr) throws Exception {
    int occurence = 0;
    lists.stream().forEach((list) -> {
        occurence += list.stream().filter((str) -> str.equals(myStr)).count();
    });
    System.out.println(occurence + " occurence found");
}
```

Comment: This is a great point.  I do need to look more into Java 8 streams as them seem to be pretty powerful.  Thanks for the cool new way of doing it

Comment: You're welcome, the stream are powerful and very optimized and fast, just try it ;)